# Spinner with long text not working fine

Tags: android, spinner, tablerow

I have some problems with the spinner. Depending of my dates, I must add to a `TableRow` a `TextView` with an `EditText` or a `Spinner`. My array that must be display in Spinner is a little long. I tested my code with an array with short texts, and it looks like this :

[image]

Here the single problem is that spinner is not `fill_parent`.

If I put my array to spinner it looks like this :

[image]

In this case, the spinner doesn't look like a spinner and the EditText is not visible any more. When I choose the spinner, it appears this view :

[image]

Here I need to display all the text of the array. 
This is my code :

```
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT , TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tablerow_product[i] = new TableRow(viewToLoad.getContext());
tablerow_product[i].setLayoutParams(lp);

product_spinner[i] = new Spinner(viewToLoad.getContext());
product_spinner[i].setLayoutParams(lp);   product_spinner[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_selector);
String[] proba={"red","blue"};  //first image is with this test array
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(viewToLoad.getContext(),  com.Orange.R.layout.my_spinner_textview,spinnerArray);                                     spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
product_spinner[i].setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
tablerow_product[i].addView(product_spinner[i]);                                            Themes_TableLayout.addView(tablerow_product[i],new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,                  TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and my_spinner_textview.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@drawable/textorange_selected"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

Can anyone help me to solve it? Any idea is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: once check this link     http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/12/dynamic-change-content-of-spinner.html

Comment: The answer of this question solved my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325242/android-how-do-i-add-1-views-in-one-cell-for-tablerow

Comment: @Bhargavi I will post an answer soon with my code.

Comment: please let me kw when you upload. Thanx in advance

Comment: @Bhargavi I post my answers below. Take a look. Maybe can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my problem I found this solution :

```
Spinner language = (Spinner) findViewById(com.Orange.R.id.current_language_text);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                com.Orange.R.layout.my_spinner_textview, languages);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(com.Orange.R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item);
language.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where languages is a `String[]` and `my_spinner_textview.xml` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview_spinner"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@drawable/textorange_selected" 
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
 />
```

Comment: Does not work for me. XML for my textview is: 
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text2"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:background="@color/edit_text_grey_bckground_color"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="11dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_nav_down"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:ellipsize="end" />

Answer (score 2):

simply I did with custom text view like:

```
ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.text_view, reasonTypesList);
myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.text_view);
mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

and here is the `text_view` layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTextView"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding"
    android:text="Custom Text with multi lines" />
```