# Add two layout parameters to addView()

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I add two layout parameters to addView() ? For example: I created first TableRow.LayoutParams whit margins for rows and second TableRow.LayoutParams with span. And then I want to add these two parameters to addView()

Here is my code:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);

        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams2= new TableRow.LayoutParams();

        tableRowParams.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
        tableRowParams2.span = 2;


        TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);



        TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
        text1.setText("text1");
        text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
        text2.setText("text2");
        text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        TextView text3 = new TextView(this);
        text3.setText("text3");
        text3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        TextView text4 = new TextView(this);
        text4.setText("text4");
        text4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        TextView text5 = new TextView(this);
        text5.setText("text5");
        text5.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        TextView text6 = new TextView(this);
        text6.setText("text6");
        text6.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        row1.addView(text1, tableRowParams);
        row1.addView(text2, tableRowParams2);

        row2.addView(text4, tableRowParams);
        row2.addView(text5, tableRowParams);
        row2.addView(text6, tableRowParams);

        tableLayout.addView(row1);
        tableLayout.addView(row2);

        setContentView(tableLayout);

    }

}
```

How can I add two parameters for row1.addView() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rafael Cardoso, you submit an idea for me. I have solved my problem this way:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams();

tableRowParams.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);

tableRowParams2.span = 2;
tableRowParams2.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

and now I can apply tableRowParams2 to any cell I want.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help !

[How can i add more than 1 Views in one cell in TableRow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325242/how-can-i-add-more-than-1-views-in-one-cell-in-tablerow)

You would need to put them in some sort of container, such as a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. There can only be one View per cell, but if that View is a container, then that one View can be actually made up of several.

Comment: I know that there can be only one View per cell, but I want to add more then one parameters to cell and not more than one View.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just define a `LayoutParams` object with both configs?

```
TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParamsExample = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
tableRowParamsExample .setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
tableRowParamsExample .span = 2;

row1.addView(text1, tableRowParamsExample);
```

However that is a work-around. You can also edit the specific LayoutParams of the rows you want to change. For instance:

```
TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);
TableRow.LayoutParams newParams = buildParams(row1);
row1.setLayoutParams(newParams);
```

And extract the logic to a method , e.g.

```
private LayoutParams buildParams(TableRow row) {
    TableRow.LayoutParams newParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(row.getLayoutParams());
    newParams.span = 12;
    return newParams
}
```

Comment: because I don't want to apply margin and span for all cells. I want just for several.